# Non restful actions in Wicked Wizard controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, wicked-gem

Can you have non-restful methods in a controller which includes the WickedWizard gem?

Controller:

```
class Books::BookUpdateController < ApplicationController

  include Wicked::Wizard
  steps :title_step,  :ai_archive_step, :ai_override_step #etc

   def show
      ...
   end

   def update
      ...
   end

   def waterfall
      ...# loads of code to set up instance variables in the view, which I don't want to have to include in the normal show action for all the wizard steps. 
   end
end
```

Routes:

```
resources :book_update do     
  member do
    get 'waterfall'
    ... and others 
  end
end
```

Version 1 and lower of the gem allows non restful actions, but [this commit](https://github.com/schneems/wicked/commit/e2124e607e5fc31800afeb58cccf19f6f44b2d91) to solve [this PR](https://github.com/schneems/wicked/pull/95) enforces step names. My error on going to this route  `http://localhost:3000/book_update/3949/waterfall` is

```
Wicked::Wizard::InvalidStepError in Books::BookUpdateController#waterfall

The requested step did not match any steps defined for this controller.
```

I suppose I should spark up a new controller and tuck the non restful actions into there, but alternatives would be great.

Comment: Since the question is related to the gem's feature/bug, I think it would be better to submit an issue or PR to the gem directly to get help quicker.

Comment: Weeell, I feel a bit bad because I should probably keep things RESTful. It's a shortcoming of me, not the gem, really.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this gem. But non-restful things are still needed in some cases. Maybe the maintainer has better opinion about it.

Comment: I believe [`Wicked`](https://github.com/schneems/wicked) uses `id` to retrieve the step, so checking if `steps` array contains the passed `id` in the `show` action then rendering accordingly might be an option.

Comment: Ooh, I like it. Ta -- I'll report back later.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add:

```
skip_before_filter :setup_wizard, only: :waterfall
```

in your wicked controller

Comment: Oh you absolute beauty!